# How to create dynamic tabSetPanels with the same selected tab that reacts to user input in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

My app contains two tabSetPanel that are created based on user input (in the example below the user input is a group of radio buttons). The user input determines both the number of tabs in both tabSetPanels **AND** the selected tab. I also want the two tabSetPanels to display the same tab whenever user input is changed or different tab is selected in either sets. The original app contains feature that prevents me from merging the two tabSetPanels. The problem is that both tabSetPanels initially display tabs without any content.
Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      # User input for number of tabs and selected tab
      radioButtons("tabSelector", "Select Number of Tabs", 1:3, 1),
      br()
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput(
        "set1"
      ),
      uiOutput(
        "set2"
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, sesstion){
  
  output$set1 <- renderUI({
    tabs <- list()
    for(i in seq_len(input$tabSelector)){
      tabs[[i]] <- tabPanel(
        title = paste0("tab",i),
        value = i,
        numericInput(
          paste0("num",i),
          "Number",
          value = 0
        )
      )
    }
    do.call(tabsetPanel, c(tabs,
                           list(id = "set1",
                                selected = input$tabSelector)))
  })
  
  output$set2 <- renderUI({
    tabs <- list()
    for(i in seq_len(input$tabSelector)){
      tabs[[i]] <- tabPanel(
        title = paste0("tab",i),
        value = i,
        numericInput(
          paste0("num",i),
          "Number",
          value = 0
        )
      )
    }
    do.call(tabsetPanel, c(tabs,
                           list(id = "set2",
                                selected = input$tabSelector)))
  })
  
  # Bind the two tabSetPanels
  observeEvent(input$set1, {
    updateTabsetPanel(inputId = "set2", selected = input$set1)
  })
  observeEvent(input$set2,{
    updateTabsetPanel(inputId = "set1", selected = input$set2)
  })
  
} # end server function

if (interactive()) {
  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The value of a `tabPanel` must be a character string :

  ```
  output$set1 <- renderUI({
    tabs <- list()
    for(i in seq_len(input$tabSelector)){
      tabs[[i]] <- tabPanel(
        title = paste0("tab",i),
        value = as.character(i),
        numericInput(
          paste0("num",i),
          "Number",
          value = 0
        )
      )
    }
    do.call(tabsetPanel, c(tabs,
                           list(id = "set1",
                                selected = as.character(input$tabSelector))
    ))
  })
  ```
- In `output$set2` you don't need to set the value of the `selected` argument, because it will be set by the `updateTabsetPanel`.
- Duplicated ids are not allowed in HTML, so you have to change the id `paste0("num",i)` of your numeric inputs to something else in one of the two tabsets.